# Rails API returning password can't be blank with has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, bcrypt

I created a new Rails app using `rails new recruiter --api -S -C -T -d postgresql` to get a bare-bones API. Then I uncommented `gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'` and ran `bundle install`. I then created a User scaffold with `rails g scaffold User email:string:uniq password_digest:string is_admin:boolean is_agent:boolean` and added `has_secure_password` to the model. When I run a POST request to `/users` I get `"password": "can't be blank"` back.

---

```
# user.rb

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
end
```

---

```
# users_controller.rb

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  def index
    @users = User.all

    render json: @users
  end

  # GET /users/1
  def show
    render json: @user
  end

  # POST /users
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
      render json: @user
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password_digest, :is_admin, :is_agent)
    end
end
```

---

Here is my JSON POST request from Postman:
[image: JSON POST request from Postman]

What am I doing wrong? I expected this to create a new User with an encrypted password saved in `password_digest`. I tried re-running the migrations and restarting the server. I tried adding an entry for `password_confirmation` to the JSON POST request. Same results. I even built a test app following all the same steps with the exception of `bcrypt` and `has_secure_password` and the POST returns the new User, so, the issue has to be with how I am using `bcrypt`. I can see in the Rails Console that the password isn't being passed along with the User, but, I don't know why.

```
Parameters: {"email"=>"user@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "is_admin"=>true, "is_agent"=>true, "user"=>{"email"=>"user@example.com", "is_admin"=>true, "is_agent"=>true}}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:20
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:20
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 17ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 6.2ms)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not permitting the password in `user_params`. May be something like following can work

```
def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :is_admin, :is_agent)
end
```

More on password digests here https://medium.com/@tpstar/password-digest-column-in-user-migration-table-871ff9120a5

Also, the JSON request needs to be wrapped in a `user` object:

```
{
  "user":
  {
    "email": "user@example.com",
    "password": "password",
    "is_admin": true,
    "is_agent": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this was half of the problem. I just figured it out also. I needed to not only allow `:password`, but, I had to wrap the JSON request in a User object like so: `{    "user":    {    "email": "user@example.com",    "password": "password",    "is_admin": true,    "is_agent": true    }    }`
Just adding `:password` to the params wasn't enough. I am going to accept your answer, though. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks :) you need to do this because you have `require(:user)` but its good practice

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password_digest, :is_admin, :is_agent)
```

you send `:password`, but permit `:password_digest`